# Groovy Jasper plugin

Tags: exception, groovy, jasper-plugin

I have updated from grails 1.1 to grails 1.1.1 and I also updated the jasper plugin from version 0.95 to version 0.97

Now I am getting an exception when calling the plugin (see below).

Any Idea what is wrong?

Thanks!

Luis

```
    2009-09-02 18:54:57,846 [2804015@qtp0-4] ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - java.lang.NullPointerException
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerInvocationException: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:92)
        at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:234)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1061)
        at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:910)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:892)
        at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:279)
        at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:274)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleGrailsControllerHelper.handleAction(SimpleGrailsControllerHelper.java:363)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleGrailsControllerHelper.executeAction(SimpleGrailsControllerHelper.java:243)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleGrailsControllerHelper.handleURI(SimpleGrailsControllerHelper.java:203)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleGrailsControllerHelper.handleURI(SimpleGrailsControllerHelper.java:138)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleGrailsController.handleRequest(SimpleGrailsController.java:88)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:48)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.GrailsDispatcherServlet.doDispatch(GrailsDispatcherServlet.java:264)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:807)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:571)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:501)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:502)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1124)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:70)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1115)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:70)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1115)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:361)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:181)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:766)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:417)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Dispatcher.forward(Dispatcher.java:334)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Dispatcher.forward(Dispatcher.java:126)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.util.WebUtils.forwardRequestForUrlMappingInfo(WebUtils.java:293)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.util.WebUtils.forwardRequestForUrlMappingInfo(WebUtils.java:269)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.util.WebUtils.forwardRequestForUrlMappingInfo(WebUtils.java:261)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping.filter.UrlMappingsFilter.doFilterInternal(UrlMappingsFilter.java:181)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1115)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.sitemesh.GrailsPageFilter.obtainContent(GrailsPageFilter.java:171)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.sitemesh.GrailsPageFilter.doFilter(GrailsPageFilter.java:110)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1115)
        at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:378)
        at org.springframework.security.intercept.web.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:109)
        at org.springframework.security.intercept.web.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
        at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
        at org.springframework.security.ui.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilterHttp(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:101)
        at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
        at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
        at org.springframework.security.providers.anonymous.AnonymousProcessingFilter.doFilterHttp(AnonymousProcessingFilter.java:105)
        at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
        at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
        at org.springframework.security.ui.rememberme.RememberMeProcessingFilter.doFilterHttp(RememberMeProcessingFilter.java:116)
        at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
        at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
        at org.springframework.security.wrapper.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilterHttp(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java
:91)
        at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
        at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
        at org.springframework.security.ui.AbstractProcessingFilter.doFilterHttp(AbstractProcessingFilter.java:277)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.springsecurity.GrailsAuthenticationProcessingFilter.super$3$doFilterHttp(GrailsAuthenticationProces
singFilter.groovy)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor865.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:86)
        at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:234)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1061)
        at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:910)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodOnSuperN(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:127)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.springsecurity.GrailsAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilterHttp(GrailsAuthenticationProcessingFilt
er.groovy:56)
        at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
        at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
        at org.springframework.security.ui.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilterHttp(LogoutFilter.java:89)
        at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
        at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
        at org.springframework.security.context.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.doFilterHttp(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.java:235)
        at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
        at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
        at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:175)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:236)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1115)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.filter.GrailsReloadServletFilter.doFilterInternal(GrailsReloadServletFilter.java:101)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1115)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.GrailsWebRequestFilter.doFilterInternal(GrailsWebRequestFilter.java:65)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1115)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:96)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:236)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1115)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:361)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:181)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:766)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:417)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:324)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:534)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:864)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:533)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:207)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:403)
        at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
        at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:522)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRPropertiesMap.readObject(JRPropertiesMap.java:185)
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:974)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1849)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1753)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1329)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1947)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1871)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1753)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1329)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readArray(ObjectInputStream.java:1667)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1323)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1947)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1871)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1753)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1329)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1947)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1871)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1753)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1329)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:351)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRLoader.loadObject(JRLoader.java:192)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperFillManager.java:361)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager$fillReport.call(Unknown Source)
        at JasperService$_closure1.doCall(JasperService.groovy:88)
        at JasperController$_closure2.doCall(JasperController.groovy:84)
        at JasperController.invokeMethod(JasperController.groovy)
        at JasperController$_closure1.doCall(JasperController.groovy:55)
        at JasperController$_closure1.doCall(JasperController.groovy)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found what was the problem.
. Under plugins\jasper-0.9.7\lib you should have **only one** version of jasperreportsXXX.jar
. If you are using Ireports for generating reports the Ireport version should be compatible with the jasperreportsXXX.jar version. That is Ireports version XXX will work with jasperreportsXXX.jar
. If you are updating the jasperreportsXXX to a newer version then most probably you have to update also theiTextXXX.jar file

Luis

Answer (score 1):

Thank you very much Luixv!
I have just had the same problem. I had only to delete one of the files in /plugins/jasper-0.9.7/lib

Comment: You are welcome! Actually I have revamped the controller in order to save reports into the DB. Also I am generating many differents reports simultaneously depending on the input form. Let me know if you need such a functionality.